# DataMapper to migrate data from one table to another.

Tags: ruby, dm

If I am using DataMapper, and I have two databases, is there any way using migration.rb to copy a table for example table person from database 1 to database 2? (same schema and table values).

Referring this:https://github.com/datamapper/dm-migrations/blob/master/examples/sample_migration.rb

It only tells me how to add/modify/drop tables.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's the intention of dm-migrations. I believe the easiest way would be something like this:

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, db1_config)
DataMapper.setup(:new, db2_config)
class Foo
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  ...
end
DataMapper.finalize

Foo.each do |foo|
  DataMapper.repository(:new) do
    # It may not let you set the "id" attribute here...
    Foo.create(foo.attributes)
  end
end
```

**Edit**

In hindsight, I'm not sure if you were asking how to to copy table structure as to opposed to table data. This is obviously copying table data.

Comment: I want to copy table data :) Thanks.