# Transfer data from one database to another with Datamapper

Tags: ruby, orm, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I have two repositories set up within data mapper as follows:

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite://path/to/db1")
DataMapper.setup(:another, "sqlite://path/to/otherdb")
```

Lets say I have a model `Foo` that they both share a schema for. This is the pseudocode that I want to accomplish:

```
DataMapper.repository(:default){
    Foo.each do |f|
        # do some transformations
        # write to Foo table in DataMapper.repository(:another)
    end
}
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Here is what you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8809259/4136098

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up doing it:

```
DataMapper.repository(:default){
    Foo.each do |foo|
        DataMapper.repository(:another){
            newFoo = Foo.new
            newFoo.attributes = foo.attributes
            newFoo.save
        }
    end
}
```